# How do I get AWS EC2 to not reset my sshd_config file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sshd

I want to allow password logins to my EC2 instances. I know which line it is that controls this in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and what it should be set to. Specifically:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

However, even when I've set this on a master image that I keep, whenever I restore it to a new instance, the value on the line keeps getting reset to 'no'. Which means that every time I launch a new instance I have to yet again manually change this file. This has made the automation of my instances one step away from being fully automated.

What do I need to do to my master image so that every instance I create from it leaves my sshd_config file the way I like?

This is a Fedora 16 image fully configured with proprietary and other software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you used an old AMI as the basis for your images, that option [used to be changed](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/cloud-kickstarts.git/commit/ec2/fedora-16-i386-ec2.ks?id=c8284fca227ec4e0e9f90a1e800651ec93c5fec3) by the kickstart file, but as far as I know that option was removed some time ago.

These days the AMI is most likely configured by [cloud-init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/) and if that is the case you should find and change the `ssh_pwauth` option in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

Comment: This will change every `PasswordAuthentication` line to `yes`, so it breaks the `Match User` construct.

Comment: in my AMI I needed to change `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/00_defaults.cfg`

Comment: As of June 2022, this works for me

Comment: And how to reload?!

Answer (score 5):

- Edit file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` (needs root permission, e.g. `sudo`)
- Look for the `ssh_pwauth` key
- Change its value from `0` to `true`.  Not `1`, but `true`!

`ssh_pwauth:   true`