# ec2-user can't login after copy AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I built an ec2 instance on aws using "Amazon Linux AMI".

I enable password login by edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
PasswordAuthentication yes

Then I setup password for ec2-user
sudo passwd ec2-user

After restart sshd, I can login to the instance as ec2-user

I installed lots of packages and setup the system over last several months.

Now I want to copy the instance to another region. 
So I created an AMI from the above instance
Copy the AMI to another region
Launch new instance from the AMI

Now I can't login to the new instance, as the new instance automatically disable password login.

When I tried to login using pem key, but got permission denied.
ssh -i "MyKeyPair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-******.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).

Any one had same problem here?

Thanks for any help.

---

Output from ssh -v

```
ssh -v -i "MyKeyPair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-221-150-254.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-221-150-254.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [18.221.150.254] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file MyKeyPair.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file MyKeyPair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-18-221-150-254.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:2PuhIWctaLlv4ZIqXKaYdWoRaj/MNoKQotjd/3dWtFw
debug1: Host 'ec2-18-221-150-254.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mli/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: MyKeyPair.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: When you try `ssh` with `-v` option, what do you get for `Authentications that can continue:`?

Comment: I posted the output from ssh -v.

Comment: The output clearly indicates `sshd` accepts only publickey. SInce password authentication is missing and the original key is not accepted, are you sure are using the correct AMI?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344390/how-do-i-get-aws-ec2-to-not-reset-my-sshd-config-file

Comment: Above link solved my problem. Thanks for all helps.